# Parse.enableLocalDatastore throw exception when application restarts

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm fighting with the well known problem of Parse.enableLocalDatastore / Parse.initialize.

Calling these first time everything goes well even if I call them from MainActivity, but after restart Parse.enableLocalDatastore throws an exception saying Parse.enableLocalDatastore should be called first :)))

I have changed my code according to several suggestions. I have created a MyApp class and moved the calls there. then I tried to modify AndroidManifest.xml. The problem is, I don't know what is the right format of android:name attribute of  tag.

Here is my application class, copy-pasted from a "working" example:

```
    package com.android.adorjan.iskolaesjatek;

    import android.app.Application;
    import com.parse.Parse;

    public class MyApp extends Application {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(){
            super.onCreate();
            // Enable Local Datastore.
            Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
            //This is what Parse was complaining about
            Parse.initialize(this, "KYZET9yhUrMQHHB", "1chhdVIUyMWkcXTlQdJl");
        }
    }
```

And here is AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.adorjan.iskolaesjatek" >

    <application
        android:name="com.android.adorjan.iskolaesjatek.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
```

But value of android:name is wrong, Android studio says 'class' or 'interface' expected. I don't  know how to spell it.

I also tried: ".MyApp", "com.android.app.MyApp" and lot of other silliness.

Thanks for any help. A really working example would be a bonus.

Comment: At least i found a solution for that problem and test it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135858/parse-error-parseenablelocaldatastorecontext-must-be-invoked-before-parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it's a known issue and it will be fixed in the next SDK release.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/IQgQ21KOBFo

Answer (score 0):

You find the answer but is good to not post your Parse credentials like that:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "KYZET9yhUrMQHHB", "1chhdVIUyMWkcXTlQdJl");
```

Comment: Since you are not answering the question, maybe put it to a comment.

Comment: Sorry for that but i'm new and don't enough reputation to put comments.