# Parse Error: Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

So i followed instructions from the Quickstart Guide from the Parse SDK Website. The app runs fine the first time around. But when I minimize the app and run it again from the task switcher, it force closes.

The error doesn't make any sense to me. Logcat -

```
05-09 08:57:40.611  19419-19419/com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook E/CrashReporting﹕ ParseCrashReporting caught a RuntimeException exception for com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook. Building report.
05-09 08:57:40.626  19419-19419/com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook E/CrashReporting﹕ Handling exception for crash
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook/com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
            at com.parse.Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Parse.java:104)
            at com.example.shubhamkanodia.bookmybook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Mainactivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!ParseCrashReporting.isCrashReportingEnabled())
            ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this); //Its already before initialize
        Parse.initialize(this, "XXX", "XXX");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can have a separate class that do this initialization stuff. So create a class `ParseApplication` that extends `Application`.

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx");
    }
  }
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml, add `ParseApplication` class to Application

```
 <application
        android:name="com.example.parsetry.ParseApplication" // you should replace this based on your package
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Can you explain how putting it in a separate class would affect the problem?

Comment: When you put the initialization in the onCreate() of a main activity, this works as long as this Activities onCreate() is not called again. The post above works by not putting the one-time initialization in the Activity but in the Application which has a different lifecycle (as shown here: https://tinyurl.com/q4bqoex ) and will only get called once. (Same effect could be reached by using a singleton like pattern).

Comment: I think that this is not a resolutive answer. I got the same error even if I've enableLocalDatastore and initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx") in the OnCreate function in the App

Comment: @P1x yes I'm seeing the same thing but only in a very low % of instances. I gave up on looking for a solution and just surrounded the `enableLocalDatastore()` call in `try..catch`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a find out a great solution for this at github that works.
put this code instead of that

Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this) .applicationId("dpynb48oUmEVzZXfU5XtUkoFOQcHyR8wKZcdQETK").clientKey("lhAqNjCKxTXlVhYjWUX25oOFRaNfGtLD97LFFO5x").server("https://parseapi.back4app.com").enableLocalDataStore() .build());